# AngularJS Schema hasn't been registered for model 'Post'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

I am trying to learn a little bit of MEAN stack and I started doing the tutorial on [thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/mean-stack-tutorial/), and I made it to the part where you need to work with the server-side, which honestly I have a lot of difficulties regarding some concepts yet, a few I am catching in, but the majority I still kinda lost. So I ask for your guys help.

First File **App.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');
require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Second File: **Index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});

router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next){
    var post = new Post(req.body);
    post.save(function(err, post){
        if(err){return next(err);}

        res.json(post);
    });
});
```

Third file, where i created the models for Post and Comment:

Posts.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Comments.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  author: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

When I do the npm start to run the web it gives me the error of Schema hasn't been registered for model "Post". 
Can you help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Check out the order of requires in app.js file, be sure to have

```
require('./models/Posts');
```

BEFORE the line

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

where you need them.

Comment: This worked for me. Is is too much to ask for a brief explanation about why this works ? :)

Comment: @pipo_dev : The file ./routes/index.js is using the model 'Post', so it must not be required before the model has been created (from PostSchema, in the tutorial).