# Thinkster MEAN Stack tutorial, error when routing/setting up REST apis with expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm currently following [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/opening-rest-routes) for creating a MEAN stack project. At this stage of the project, I'm using Express to open up rest routes on the Mongo database. Here is the code I add to the top of /routes/index.js (autocreated with express --ejs).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
```

When I try to run the server using npm start, npm exits with an exit status 1, with a failure on the ./bin/www initial script. Here's the debug log as well as the code for /routes/index.js and the file where the Post schema is created, /models/Posts.js. Does anyone know how to solve this? If you need any more information let me know.

./routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
//var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

./models/Posts.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
});

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v7.2.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~prestart: bluenews@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart,continuing
7 info lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~start: bluenews@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/user/Dropbox/Coding/redditClone/bluenews/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/user/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~start: CWD: /home/user/Dropbox/Coding/redditClone/bluenews
11 silly lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node ./bin/www' ]
12 silly lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle bluenews@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: bluenews@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid bluenews@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/user/Dropbox/Coding/redditClone/bluenews
17 error Linux 4.4.0-53-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v7.2.1
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error bluenews@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bluenews@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bluenews package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node ./bin/www
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs bluenews
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls bluenews
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the 'Post' in your Post.js file, then only it is visible to other modules.

In your case, You have to do the below steps

```
var Post=mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
module.exports=Post;
```

and then you need to import this file as below

```
 var Post = mongoose.model('./models/Posts.js');
```

You also need to include path module in index.js file
ex:

```
 var path = require('path');
```

after the line var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

Comment: Thanks! This helped me hunt down the issue, which was that the mongoose schemas weren't being recognized. I boiled it down to the imports in the app.js was requiring the routes files before the model files. For anyone else having issues, [here's the stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762913/angularjs-schema-hasnt-been-registered-for-model-post) I found after more troubleshooting.